# Can we use contains attribute in iloc in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Ques :  I have to loop in set of series to find out whether any of the series value contains the subset string "Hi"?

EXPLANATION: Here there are two Dataframes Dataframe1 and Dataframe2 and I´m trying to find if Dataframe2's 'Source Code' contains Dataframe1's string and set the result in Dataframe3.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl

data = {'Fields' : ['Hi', 'How', 'Are', 'You']}

Dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data2 = {'SourceCode' : ['LMNOHiPQR', 'LMNOHowPQR']}

Dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

data3 = {'dummy' : []}

Dataframe3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)

for i in range(0,len(Dataframe1)):      
    current_string=Dataframe1['Fields'][i]
    for j in range(0,len(Dataframe2)): 
            if Dataframe2['SourceCode'].iloc[j].contains(current_field):
                Dataframe3['dummy'].iloc[j] =Dataframe2['SourceCode'].iloc[j]
```

EXPECTATION: I expect the 'SourceCode' values which contains the strings from Dataframe1 to set in Dataframe3. but I get the below error.

```
RESULT: 
if Dataframe2['SourceCode'].iloc[j].contains(current_field):

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

Guys as an addition to the previous question i now want to add a seperate column in Dataframe3 with respective string (i.e current_field). Hence i will know the observation corresponds to which string. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you should use the `in` operator to test if a substring exists in a string, so you're loop should be something like:

```
for i in range(0,len(Dataframe1)):      
    current_string=Dataframe1['Fields'][i]
    for j in range(0,len(Dataframe2)): 
        if current_string in Dataframe2['SourceCode'].iloc[j]:
                Dataframe3.loc[j, 'dummy'] = Dataframe2['SourceCode'].iloc[j]
```

However, looping with `pandas.DataFrames` is not advised. So an alternative solution could be to use the [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) method and [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
Dataframe3 = Dataframe2[Dataframe2.SourceCode.str.contains('|'.join(Dataframe1.Fields))]
```

[out]

```
                                   SourceCode
0   try{string s = "Hi"}catch { }return null;
1  try{string s = "How"}catch { }return null;
```

And if you require the matches to include word-boundaries, instead create your regex pattern first like:

```
pat = r'\b' + r'\b|\b'.join(Dataframe1.Fields) + r'\b'
Dataframe3 = Dataframe2[Dataframe2.SourceCode.str.contains(pat)]
```

Comment: Thank you, So much Chris. It's Working!

Comment: Hi Chris as an addition to the previous question i now want to add a seperate column in Dataframe3 with respective string (i.e current_field). Hence i will know the observation corresponds to which string. Please help me on this.